# Server to iOS message whilst app is closed

Tags: ios, notifications, location

I would like to send a message from my web server to my iOS app in any state, including 'Not running'. Does iOS provide any system level functionality that can do this?

The closest I have found is Push Notification Background Download, but I don't want the user seeing the notification.

What I am trying to implement is the opposite of a typical geofence. I want to notify the user when something happens but only if they're within a certain area. i.e. Not when they enter a geofence.

I was hoping I could notify the app, check the location and then notify the user if they're in the area. Otherwise ignore the event.

Comment: This may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8716470/4797324

Comment: If the user has terminated your app (swipe up) then silent push notifications are not received. If the app is suspended or was terminated by iOS for memory pressure then silent push notifications are received.