# How do I Modify a Local Notifications TItle Before Showing Notification for iOS Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, uilocalnotification

I am using the MS example for showing a local notification. I am scheduling a daily repeating notification and need to modify the title and message each day based on an API call. I tried modifying the title & message that is sent to `iOSNotificationManager.ReceiveNotification()` at  [L31 in iOSNotificationReceiver.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.iOS/iOSNotificationReceiver.cs#L31), but the original title/body is always shown in the notification.

I thought maybe I could not show the original notification and create a new notification to be shown in 1 second; janky I know but it was an idea. The trouble I ran into here is that the original notification is shown even if I return at [L72 in iOSNotificationManager.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications/LocalNotifications.iOS/iOSNotificationManager.cs#L72) before `NotificationReceived?.Invoke(null, args);` is called.

So how do I modify the title and message when just as the notification is being shown? This works perfectly fine in Android.

One thing I could do is only schedule 1 notification and when the notification is shown schedule tomorrows notification. However, if for some reason the notification was never shown one day then the next day would not be schedule therefor canceling the daily scheduled notification.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/local-notifications/

Comment: Maybe [Invisible Notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8716470/ios-push-services-is-an-invisible-push-notification-possible)?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve brilliant, thank you. Now to work out the issue that I get 5 duplicate notifications when sending a notification from the notification receiver when I only get 1 when sending from the UI.

Comment: Will do. @ToolmakerSteve I think this might be impossible in my instance. I need to update the notification when the app is either closed or in the background. This question says there is not callback when the app is not in the foreground therefore leaving no way to modify the notification or create a new notification with the correct text. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064835/ios-local-notification-callback-when-in-background

Comment: See [Pushing Background Updates to your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/pushing_background_updates_to_your_app). Looks like you could wake the app in the background. Do that once a day, invisibly. (Probably requires an additional permission.) At that time, create the updated visible notification. BTW, did you test your Android solution when the app wasn't running? It should have the same problem as you have on iOS - the user will see outdated text, unless you do something like the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modifying the data shown in a notification for iOS is impossible after the notification has been set. There is no callback method that can be used in iOS like on Android when a notification is shown.

To set the daily notification on repeat with different message the best course of action is to use push notifications. However, not having push notifications setup I set up 64 notifications, which is the max iOS allows, for the next 64 days.

Note: iOS only allows 64 notifications to be set per app.